# Dynamically adding routerlink for a button from a Select option's value

Tags: typescript, angular6

Here is the example for my Question

sample.component.html

```
<div class="center">
<div class="form-group" >
<label>Select Country</label>
<select class="form-control">
  <option *ngFor="let o of options">{{o.name}}</option>
</select>  
<button><a [routerLink]="[o.value]">Submit</a></button>
</div>
</div>
```

sample.component.ts

```
export class SelectLocationComponent {
selectedOption: string;
options = [
{ name: "All Countries", value: '/allcountries' },
{ name: "India", value: '/india' }
]
}
```

I want the selected o.value in the `routerlink`
from the `sample.component.ts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ngmodel` variable inside `routerlink` like this

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Select Country</label>
        <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
          <option *ngFor="let o of options" [value]="o.value">{{o.name}} 
          </option>
        </select>  
<button><a [routerLink]="selectedOption">Submit</a></button>
{{selectedOption}}
      </div>
</div>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routerlink-ssf-6rbdyq)

Comment: @AswinKumar check my demo